# How can I get the name of the current thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

The title says it all. In a Java app, how can I reliably get the name of the thread that is currently running?

Also, if I start the app in the EDT (using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`), and never explicitly start another thread - the entire program will stay in the EDT - right?

Comment: What do you mean by _reliable_?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't know, threads are tricky

Comment: Any such info is stale by the time it's returned, which is why OS don't offer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Thread.currentThread().getName()
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you answer my second question please?

Comment: Is it relevant to the title of your question? please ask in separate thread to make it visible for others also.

Comment: But still I'll answer your question here.